# The video starts to play when the application run. How to avoid this?

Tags: android-studio, android-listview, android-videoview

I made a listview with a videoview. When the application is running, the video starts automatically playing. I don't want that. The video should start playing when I click on it. I made an Adapter.

ArrayAdapter

```
MediaController mc;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View listViewItem = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.symptomlistitem, parent, false);
        TextView txtSymptom = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtSymptom);
        VideoView videoSymptom = (VideoView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.videoSymptom);

        Symptom symptom = this.getItem(position);

        txtSymptom.setText(symptom.getSymptom());
        videoSymptom.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.speechrecogniser/" + (symptom.getVideo())));
        videoSymptom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoSymptom.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.setAnchorView(videoSymptom);
        videoSymptom.start();
        return listViewItem;
    }
```

I've added the MediaController, but it didn't work. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The videos start immediately because you added `videoSymptom.start()` on the `getView()` method, therefore when the videos are populated on the list they will start immediately.

One possible solution will be to remove this statement and make sure the `.start()` method is invoked only when you click on the video's widget:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View listViewItem = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.symptomlistitem, parent, false);
    TextView txtSymptom = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtSymptom);
    final VideoView videoSymptom = (VideoView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.videoSymptom);

    Symptom symptom = this.getItem(position);

    txtSymptom.setText(symptom.getSymptom());
    videoSymptom.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.speechrecogniser/" + (symptom.getVideo())));
    videoSymptom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoSymptom.setMediaController(mc);
    videoSymptom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            videoSymptom.start();        
        }
    });
    mc.setAnchorView(videoSymptom);
    return listViewItem;
}
```

Comment: The application opens and closes immediately.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is :(

Comment: Now I have this error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.MediaController.setAnchorView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference